# Upload completion event in Ext.net (ASP.NET)?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, dom-events, ext.net

How can I show a message when the ext.net's **FileUploadField** complete. (With Javascript on clientside).

My code for using ext.net UploadField:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function checkExtension(value) {
        if (value.match("\.png$") != null || value.match("\.jpg$") != null
        || value.match("\.jpeg$") != null || value.match("\.gif$") != null) 
            return true;
        alert("The file must be image");
        return false;
    }
</script>

<ext:FileUploadField ID="FileUploadField1" runat="server" Icon="Attach" ButtonText="Select File" Visible="true" ButtonOffset="1" ButtonOnly="true" Validator="checkExtension">
    <DirectEvents>
        <FileSelected OnEvent="ImageFileSelected" />
    </DirectEvents>
</ext:FileUploadField>
```

Comment: i haven't use ext.net yet, but i can help you with YUI uploader. have a look here `http://labs.deeptechtons.com/asp-net-tuts/how-to-upload-files-asynchronously-using-yahoo-uploader/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First solution (full client side):

```
<ext:FileUploadField ID="FileUploadField1" runat="server" Icon="Attach" ButtonText="Select File" Visible="true" ButtonOffset="1" ButtonOnly="true" Validator="checkExtension">
    <DirectEvents>
        <FileSelected OnEvent="ImageFileSelected" 
              Success="Ext.Msg.alert('Success');" 
              Failure="Ext.Msg.alert('Failure');" />
    </DirectEvents>
</ext:FileUploadField>
```

Second solution (server side script generation):

```
public void ImageFileSelected(object sender, DirectEventArgs e) {
    if (this.FileUploadField1.HasFile) {
        // save file here

        X.Msg.Show(new MessageBoxConfig {
           Buttons = MessageBox.Button.OK,
           Icon = MessageBox.Icon.INFO,
           Title = "Success",
           Message = string.Format(tpl, this.FileUploadField1.PostedFile.FileName,  
           this.FileUploadField1.PostedFile.ContentLength)
        });
    }
}
```

And you can look here http://examples.ext.net/#/Form/FileUploadField/Basic/

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to do this.

A "cheap trick" approach is to add a blank literal to your page and update it's text during the onfileuploaded event (or whatever event you want) with the text needed to fire your javascript function.  *(Note that this approach only works if there's an actual page postback!)*

Another approach (and considered the "correct" way) to manage this in ASP.NET is to add a scriptmanager to your page and register your clientscript with it in the onfileuploaded event (or whatever event you want).  Code examples for those are numerous and easily [google-able.](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&source=hp&q=asp.net+scriptmanager+tutorial&pbx=1&oq=asp.net+scriptmanager+tutorial&aq=f&aqi=g1&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=602l5866l0l6075l32l22l1l0l0l0l237l3550l2.13.7l22l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.,cf.osb&fp=55ec5d59dd72fa0b&biw=1082&bih=712)